# Linear Algebra, Least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I'm going through the Linear Algebra course on Brilliant.org, but can't figure out how I should know that $\frac{17}{3}$ is the best value for $c$ to fill in here.

My two questions are:

1) Why do we want to minimize the distance of

$$3c^2-34c+101$$

2) How can you derive where this distance is minimised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to minimize the distance of $c\pmatrix{1 \\ 1 \\ 1} -2 \pmatrix{1 \\ 2 \\ 3}$ to the vector $\pmatrix{5 \\ 0 \\ 0}$.

We have

$$\left\|c\pmatrix{1 \\ 1 \\ 1} -2 \pmatrix{1 \\ 2 \\ 3} - \pmatrix{5 \\ 0 \\ 0}\right\|^2 = \left\|\pmatrix{c-7 \\ c-4 \\ c-6}\right\|^2 = (c-7)^2+(c-4)^2+(c-6)^2 = 3c^2-34c+101$$

To minimize the polynomial $3c^2-34c+101$, write it as

$$3c^2-34c+101 = 3\underbrace{\left(c - \frac{17}3\right)^2}_{\ge 0} + \frac{14}3$$

so the minimum is attained for $c = \frac{17}3$ and it is equal to $\frac{14}3$.

Comment: Thanks! So then this is the closest we can get to a real answer right? The "best" solution we can derive given there is no real possible solution

Comment: @Daphne Yes, the closest solution of the form $\pmatrix{c \\ -2}$ is  $\pmatrix{\frac{17}3 \\ -2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Find the derivative of the polynomial given.  The root is the number 17/3...

Comment: So you mean, first remove the ^2 from the polynomial so you are left with 3c - 34c + 101. Then take the derivative so you get 17/3 correct?

Comment: Can you give some intuition as in why we take the derivative in this case?

Comment: 6c-34.please note that minimum of the poly is the root of the last you mentioned

Comment: You need to find the minimum of the function f=3c^2-34+101. One way to do this is with the help of derivative...